# Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL' not allowed in this context

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, oracle9i

I'm having this error while trying to compile the following trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INCREMENTER_ID_CONSISTANCE 

BEFORE INSERT ON BD.CONSISTANCE 
for each row
BEGIN
:new.code := ID_CONSISTANCE.nextval;
END;  


**ERROR** : Table,View Or Sequence reference 'ID_CONSISTANCE.nextval' not allowed in
this context
```

What is the problem here ? and how can I fix this ?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Assuming the underlying definitions support it, this syntax looks valid in 11.1 and later.  But it would not be valid in earlier versions of Oracle.

Comment: what Oracle version are you using ? It seems that it 10g or earlier.

See here 

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/oracle-pl-sql/9780137151684/introduction-pl-sql-new-features-in-oracle-11g/pref03lev1sec4

Comment: @JustinCave Blood-Hazard I'm using Oracle 9i :)

Comment: I think you need to use a 'select <from sequence> into <variable> from dual' to do what you wish.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes that was the case thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This syntax is only allowed in Oracle 11 or later.

The (unsupported and outdated) 9i version did not support direct assignment of a sequence value.

You need to use a `select into` instead:

```
select ID_CONSISTANCE.nextval
  into :new.code 
FROM dual;
```

And you should *really* plan an upgrade to a current version of Oracle (11.x or 12.x)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name very much :) between could you please tell me why I have to upgrade to a later version ?

Comment: @mounaim Because 9i is unsupported (and has been for several years now) and won't get any security or bug fixes.